# New versions of LD cannot take ELF files as input to link

Tags: linux, makefile, operating-system, ld, elf

I have been working on a 32-bit operating system project written in C using GNU LD version 2.34 as the linker.

As part of the build process, I use the following command:

`ld -m elf_i386 -nostdlib -T ld/loader.ld build/bootloader/loader.o build/bootloader/loader.elf -o loader_full.elf`

When using GNU LD version 2.34, this command succeeds. However, when I use a version higher than this, I get the following error:

`ld: cannot use executable file 'build/bootloader/loader.elf' as input to a link`

If necessary, here is the full Makefile script:

```
CC_FLAGS = -g -m32 -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector
LD_FLAGS = -m elf_i386 -nostdlib

CC := gcc ${CC_FLAGS}
LD := ld ${LD_FLAGS} 

BOOTLOADER_DRIVERS = kernel/drivers/disk/ata.c kernel/drivers/io/screen.c kernel/drivers/utils/mem.c kernel/drivers/utils/ports.c

raw: prep os-image.bin

convert_vmdk: os-image.vmdk 

all: prep os-image.bin

ESFS_raw_write: ESFS_raw_write.c
    gcc $^ -o $@

# run OS in QEMU
run: 
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=os-image.bin

# assemble boot sector
build/bootloader/boot_sect.bin: boot/boot_sect.asm
    nasm $^ -f bin -o $@

# compile second stage bootloader
build/bootloader/loader_2.o build/drivers/*.o: boot/*.c ${BOOTLOADER_DRIVERS}
    ${CC} -c $^
    mv loader.o build/bootloader/loader_2.o
    mv *.o build/drivers/

# link object files into kernel loader
build/bootloader/loader.elf: build/bootloader/loader_2.o build/drivers/*.o
    ${LD} -T ld/loader.ld $^ -o $@
    rm build/bootloader/loader_2.o

# assemble first stage bootloader
build/bootloader/loader.o: boot/loader.asm
    nasm $^ -f elf -o $@

# link first and second stage bootloaders
build/bootloader/loader_full.elf: build/bootloader/loader.o build/bootloader/loader.elf
    ${LD} -T ld/loader.ld $^ -o $@

# make bootloader binary file
build/bootloader/loader.bin: build/bootloader/loader_full.elf
    objcopy $^ -O binary $@
    ./scripts/pad_loader.sh
    # clean up unnecessary files
    # rm build/bootloader/*.o build/bootloader/*.elf build/drivers/*.o

build/kernel/interrupt.o: kernel/cpu/interrupt.asm
    nasm $^ -f elf -o $@

# compile kernel & write to 10MB raw drive image
build/kernel/hdd.bin: kernel/drivers/*/*.c kernel/cpu/*.c kernel/libc/*.c build/kernel/interrupt.o kernel/*.c
    ${CC} $^ -o build/kernel/kernel.o -T ld/kernel.ld
    ./scripts/write_kernel_to_drive.sh

# concat 3 boot stages into os-image file
os-image.bin: build/bootloader/boot_sect.bin build/bootloader/loader.bin build/kernel/hdd.bin
    cat $^ > $@

os-image.vmdk: 
    VBoxManage convertfromraw os-image.bin os-image.vmdk --format VMDK
    VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid /home/tim/Dev/OSDev/os-image.vmdk 6372c00a-a62e-4241-9a21-90fa4c22f019

# prepare directory structure for build process
prep:
    mkdir -p build/bootloader
    mkdir -p build/drivers
    mkdir -p build/kernel

# clean up build files and os-image binary
clean:
    -rm -rf build/
    -rm *.bin *.vmdk
    -rm ESFS_raw_write
```

The project is also on GitHub, so you can build it for yourself:
http://github.com/TimCve/OSDev.git

Comment: I'm having this error and the object it complains about has type shared object so it's not even executable. Worked fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Moved to Ubuntu 22.04 and doesn't work. :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just come up with a similar problem.

It seems ld version `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1` links the file into an executable format.

To fix it, add `-r` in your `ld` command to output a relocatable format file.

From the [ld manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html):

> -r
> --relocateable
> Generate relocatable output--i.e., generate an output file that can in turn serve as input to ld. This is often called partial linking. As a side effect, in environments that support standard Unix magic numbers, this option also sets the output file's magic number to OMAGIC. If this option is not specified, an absolute file is produced. When linking C++ programs, this option will not resolve references to constructors; to do that, use `-Ur`. This option does the same thing as `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

In my (eclipse-based) multicore MCUXpresso project, I had to add this line to my post-build steps to modify a byte inside of the generated "*.o" file so the linker step which used that file wouldn't complain anymore.  This happened after I updated to version 11.6 which includes the LD version mentioned previously.  I originally found this on the forums for NXP MCUXpresso, but I assume it will work similarly for just about anyone:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of="${BuildArtifactFileName}.o" bs=1 seek=16 conv=notrunc count=2
```

[NXP MCUXpresso fix](https://community.nxp.com/t5/MCUXpresso-General/ld-2-37-won-t-link-in-an-executable-file-M0A-or-M0S-application/td-p/1420623)

Comment: I'm speechless.  Or I was, anyway.  On one hand, hooray that your build works for you.  On the other hand, that approach is absolutely horrifying.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that `ld` can't take ELF files as input.  It's that it won't take *executable* files as input.  The error is:

> ld: cannot use executable file '...' as input to a link

See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26223

Does it work to simply use `chmod -x $@` after building the `.elf` file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't work, even if the file is not executable I get the exact same error, is there a way to make LD able to take executable files as input?

Comment: I guess it's not looking at the bits, it's looking at something in the file itself.  I have no solution other than dropping back to an older version and waiting for the above bug to be fixed (or you can build your own applying the patch).  you probably should add a note to that bug asking what the status is, since it doesn't seem to have been touched in >1 year and there have been binutils releases since, including one just a couple of weeks ago.  Maybe this dropped off everyone's radar.